# Does Updating the Target in a Pre-Operation Cause Other Plugins to Trigger?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

Given:

1. Two plugins registered against the Synchronous pre-operation of Contact, Plugin A, and Plugin B,
2. Plugin A's Execution Order is 1, and Plugin B's Execution Order is 2

If Plugin B updates the target entity (no IOrganizationService Update, just a standard update of the in memory CRM entity object itself) will this change to the target trigger Plugin A to fire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as long as IOrganizationService update is not called a new update event is not triggered. Triggering the same plugin event on adding attributes to the existing target entity would end up causing infinite loops.

Comment: So then, using a plugin, you could cause a change to an entity via the target, that a plugin filtered for that specific change would not get triggered?

Comment: No, it wouldn't, now if you happen to have a second plugin or a step with a higher execution order, if it is a step, configured to filter on all attributes (update) or configured to fire on create, it would fire and you would see the attribute added/updated by the first plugin, but if you happen to register the second plugin on a specific attribute which you have changed from the first plugin, the plugin would not get fired.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on this, or is it all from personal experience?

Comment: Personal experience, but I did verify your exact scenario with a few test plugins and it did exhibit the expected behavior.